# Selenium not finding elements when running tests as suite

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I go strange problem with selenium when I am running them as group.
Let me describe my problem in more details. When I am running just one test from ide everything is ok. But when I am trying to run them as a group always first test is passing, but after that tests are failing. In each of test I am finding and clicking same button. There is no problem with xPath because in chrome console element is found.
After every test, I have method which is returning website to home location.
Ach, and elements which I am testing are located in `iFrame`.

So let me copy paste some example code.

Api Class:

```
public class SiteImpl implemets BasicSite {
.
.
.
static {
    swtichToTestedFrame();
}

private SiteImpl() {};

public static SiteImpl get() {
    return new SiteImpl ();
}

@Override
public void clickCreateButton() {
    Utils.findElementByXpathAndParam(XPath.DIV_TITLE_XPATH, BUTTON_TITLE).orElseThrow(
            () -> new NoSuchElementException("Create button does not exist")).click();
}

private static void swtichToTestedFrame() {
    WebElement iFrameElement = Utils.findElementByXpath(XPath.IFRAME_XPATH).orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("iFrame does not exist"));
    XdmWebDriver.getWebDriver().switchTo().frame(iFrameElement);
}
}
```

And lets say all tests looks like this, as I mentioned before only first test is passing. Event if all of them are the same.

```
 @Test
 public void test() {
   ExportManagerImpl.get().clickCreateTask();
 }
```

Obviously there is before and after method. Code is simplified obviously.

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Create button does not exist
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'xxxx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_162'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Comment: provide console error also when running as group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you to call `swtichToTestedFrame()` at constructor instead of static block.

Could you please provide how you are grouping tests and the complete file with @Before and @Test. It will be helpful for me to understand it better.

Comment: Seems like problem was with static block I did try to put this code into constructor and changed a little implementation of method and everything i alright